# Android Studio build configuration problem with gradle sync

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

I was trying my first android project via Android Studio but meanwhile the build configuration process i got this error :

```
A problem occurred configuring root project 'My Application'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not download gradle.jar (com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3)
      > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.5.3/gradle-3.5.3.jar'.
         > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.5.3/gradle-3.5.3.jar'. Received status code 501 from server: Tor is not an HTTP Proxy
```

it's so weird because i was not using any proxies in http proxy setting of IDE !( I know Tor is a socks5 proxy ) and when i checked my connection via http proxy setting it is okay also i can download each required dependency using my browser 
how can i fix this mess ? 
tnx

Comment: can you please add your `build.gradle` code here

Comment: // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        
        
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3'
        
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

Comment: Are you running Tor?

Comment: sorry mean in your questions

Comment: I was using tor long ago but i configured IDE to not use tor proxy but it didnt work so i edited gradle.properties in .gradle

Answer (score 0):

So far we were used to use a « gradle.properties » file per project. There is now a global one in ".gradle" directory.So i  checked that it contains the correct informations about my proxy.

So I just editted proxy setting in the ~/.gradle/gradle.properties
Problem Solved =)
May the force be with Us